# When creating a record, copy an attribute from a associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails to-do app, I have a Tasks model. Tasks can be `blocked_by` each other. Each task has a User. When I do `taskA.blocked_by.create(name: "Task B")`, I would like Task B to get the same User that Task A has.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to refer to the record that's creating the current record. I need to learn how to get `taskA.user` so I can automatically assign it to `taskB`. I'd rather not have to do that manually every time I create a blocked_by task.

I've tried setting `self.user` in a `before_validation` method.

```rb
before_validation :inherit_user, on: :create

private
    def inherit_user
        if self.user == nil 
            p "Task #{self.name} missing user"
            if self.blocked_by.count > 0
                self.user = self.blocked_by.first.user
                p "Inheriting user from first blocked_by task #{self.blocked_by.first.name}"
            end
        end
    end
```

This doesn't work because `self.blocked_by` is empty because the record isn't saved yet.

[Rails' documentation on association class methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) leads me to believe I should be able to do something like this:

```rb
has_many :blocked_by do |owner|
    def create(attributes)
        p owner # access properties from association owner here
        attributes.push(user: owner.user)
        super
    end
end
```

When I try this I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `owner' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>)
```

**Edit:** Here's my model file:

```rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, :presence => true

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :children, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "parent_id"
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Task", optional: true
    has_ancestry

    # thanks to https://medium.com/@jbmilgrom/active-record-many-to-many-self-join-table-e0992c27c1e
    has_many :blocked_blocks, foreign_key: :blocker_id, class_name: "BlockingTask"
    has_many :blocked_by, through: :blocked_blocks, source: :blocking, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :blocker_blocks, foreign_key: :blocked_id, class_name: "BlockingTask"
    has_many :blocking, through: :blocker_blocks, source: :blocker, dependent: :destroy

    has_many_attached :attachments

    before_validation :inherit_user, on: :create

    def completed_descendants
        self.descendants.where(completed: true)
    end

    def attachment_count
        self.attachments.count
    end

    private
        def inherit_user
            if self.user == nil and self.parent
                self.user = self.parent.user
            end
        end

end
```

I can `inherit_user` from a parent task, like so: `taskA.children.create(name: "Task B")`. I'd like to do the same for a `blocked_by` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

To refer to the current record which is supposed to be created, try running `before_create` callback.

```
 before_create :inherit_user
```

and the `self.blocked_by` now must have a value.

Comment: When I change :inherit_user from before_validate to before_create, the model fails validation and the callback doesn't run at all.

Comment: I need to have a look at your validations, also how are you getting the value of blocked_by (if you are not asking it from the user  then it is supposed to be empty, and you need to define it before you can use it inside an if statement).
If that is not the case show me your model file and the create method.

Comment: I've edited my model file into the question. Figuring out how to define the value of blocked_by is exactly what I'm trying to do. I don't have a custom create method.

Comment: To get the user name of the Task you can use

`Task.includes(:user).first.user.name`

It takes the first task in the database and includes the user it belongs to and returns its name, change the syntax according to the task that you need.
Hope this is what you're looking for.